# Historical Walmart Stores Data set

Tags: data-request, historical, programming

I'm trying to capture a historical list of Wal-mart stores. I need store ID, store name, longitude, latitutde, address, city, state, zip, services, store opening date, and store closing date (if the store shut down). I'm trying to connect to the Wal-mart API but not able to get an access key. I work in R. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open Street Map (OSM) has a tag *name=Walmart*.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:name%3DWalmart

Note:

> In December 2017 Brandify provided Open Street Map with a database of all Walmart locations, and details This import took place January 2nd, 2018 and used OSM Conflator.

So it's unlikely to have when the store was opened.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas J. Holmes compiled data on Walmart store openings from 1962-2006, [which you can download](http://users.econ.umn.edu/~holmes/data/WalMart/index.html)

You could compare to the [2017 data from Brandify](http://audit.osmz.ru/project/walmart/) to find stores opened since 2006 (which stayed open until 2017).

I don't know of any source of store-closing data.